# Call tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue('LOCALE', onSuccess, onError) sometimes neither onSuccess nor onError is called

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app

I want to get device language on Tizen SmartTV, call the api, but sometimes there is no response after call the method.

```
tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue('LOCALE',
            systemInfoLocale => {
                console.log(systemInfoLocale.language);
                resolve(systemInfoLocale.language);
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
                reject('API error get language');
            }
        );
```

sometimes it works correctly, but in most cases it works incorrectly, and the 'onSuccess' or 'onError' is not called yet. Is there anyone get the issuse ?